# Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession json data Content-Type not received

Tags: c++, json, node.js, http, poco-libraries

So I am developing a server side Nodejs/expressjs app and a clientside c++/Poco app. I've managed to create a session between where the server is hosted and client. However, any time i try to send my JSON payload, express.js shows req.body as empty.

Google didn't reveal much besides that Content-Type was likely not being transmitted correctly and it appears so. I do set it explicitly but apparently i'm missing a step.

client-side

```
void upload(std::list<std::string>& args) {
    if (args.size() == 0 || args.front() == "--help") {
        help("upload");
        return;
    }

    std::string repo = args.front();
    args.pop_front();

    std::string name, language;
    auto depends = getDepends(name, language);

    // start making the poco json object here
    Poco::JSON::Object obj;
    obj.set("name", name);
    obj.set("url", repo);

    Poco::URI uri("http://url-of-my-server:50001/make_repo");
    std::string path(uri.getPathAndQuery());


    if (path.empty()) path = "/";

    HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
    HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, path, HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    HTTPResponse response;

    std::ostream& o = session.sendRequest(request);

    std::cout << response.getStatus() << " " << response.getReason() << std::endl;

    session.setKeepAlive(true);
    request.setContentType("application/json");  // definately set Content-Type right?
    obj.stringify(std::cout);                    // can confirm it is spitting out the valid json here
    obj.stringify(o);                            // place the json in the request stream

    std::istream& s = session.receiveResponse(response);

    // do stuff with returned data
}
```

server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var database = require('./database.js');  // one of my files
var connection = database.connection;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = 50001;   // explicitly set port because environment port kept forcing port 3000

// just a callback to make sure i'm connected to my sql server
connection.query('SELECT 1',function(err, rows) {
    if(err) {
        console.error("Could not connect to the database.");
    } else {
        console.log('connected to database: ' + connection.threadId);
    }

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.send('hello world');
    });

    // this is the route I invoke, (and it is definately invoked)
    app.post('/make_repo', function(req, res, next) {

        console.log(req.headers); // this always returns '{ connection: 'Close', host: 'url-of-my-server:50001' }
        console.log(req.body); // this always returns '{}'

    });

    var listener = app.listen(port, function() {
        console.log("port: " + listener.address().port);
    });

});
```

It appears that this is on Poco's end because I can transmit test data from postman and it reports just fine. I also setKeepAlive to true on Poco and that appears to be ignored as well. Has anyone used Poco enough to help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a little confused by the stateful stream style of communication. It is http and technically still a stateless connection. All of the information about the request, EXCEPT THE BODY, must be done before you send the initial request.

```
HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, path, HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
HTTPResponse response;

std::stringstream ss;
obj.stringify(ss);
request.setKeepAlive(true);
request.setContentLength(ss.str().size());
request.setContentType("application/json");  // definately set Content-Type right?

std::ostream& o = session.sendRequest(request);
obj.stringify(o);             // can confirm it is spitting out the valid 

std::cout << response.getStatus() << " " << response.getReason() << std::endl;
```

Also, needed to set the contentLength which I'd tried before but wasn't working due to the content-type not being sent properly. After the content length and type were set right, the server received correctly without a hitch.

Comment: Thanks for posting this Q&A - can't see why anyone would downvote it without comment - examples are sparse enough for Poco without such discouragement. But... how does that last line possibly work? That is, `response` appears not to be connected up to anything - is there code missing?

Comment: Oh yes there actually are some lines missing. Prolly why i was downvoted. Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/FatalCatharsis/749d93b4592e7d59d91a) gist, it shows a complete example.

Comment: Yeah - I realised that there needed to be a `session.receiveResponse()` call... but there is still something missing with `obj.stringify(ss)` - how does that data make it into the request? It would be good to edit your answer with a fully tested solution

Comment: @omatai - That gist contained what is now being used in the production code, (sensitive stuff omitted). The stringstreams purpose is only to get the length of the json content that will be put in the buffer. obj.stringify sticks the contents of the json object "obj" into the stringstream which you set the content length with. Then later, when you invoke session.sendRequest(request), you obtain the actual ostream it will use to stream data. The call to obj.stringify(o) is how the data ends up in the request. I will edit my answer when I find some time.